# Publishing model with custom script containing call to .exe on Geoprocessing server

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, modelbuilder, python-script-tool, geoprocessing-service

I have a ModelBuilder model that uses a custom python script, and within the script there is a call to a command line interface (CLI) executable. The model runs fine on my local desktop, but when I go to publish the results to a GP server, I get the error:

[image]

My first question is:

What's the difference between a model that uses a custom python script, and a python toolbox?

I've successfully published a python toolbox that contains a call to the same _cli.exe, but for other reasons needed to try converting the tool to a model.

My second question:

What are my options, if any, for using a tool on a GP server that calls the .exe?

The machine running the GP server already has the program associated with the cli.exe installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of someone using what you've created: there is no difference. Its a tool.
Technically speaking a python toolbox (.pyt) is a python script but structured in a way that ArcGIS understands its a toolbox + tool. The model and script tool are something that live inside a toolbox (.tbx). The script tool references an independent python file (.py) or can embed it inside the .tbx. Or you can put a tool in a tool which is fine too: python script tool inside your model.

Per the solutions ([right click on that error and select help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000601000000)): you'll want to register the folder that .exe lives in with the datastore. Thus server "wont try to copy the exe".